# Firefox in popup window (no address search bar) ctrl-k navigates to google

Tags: firefox, keyboard-shortcuts, search

In firefox hitting <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd> takes you to the search bar (all fine and good).

However in my webmail client (Zimbra) it pops open windows without the address/search bar.  Hitting <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd> there (muscle memory from Outlook Web Access) navigates immediately to google.com - hitting back doesn't work from there (Zimbra's all screwed).

Is there anyway to disable <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd> navigating to the search provider *without changing the normal <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd> to the search-bar behaviour when the search-bar is present*?

Or better yet force it to actually pop up the search-bar - or highlight in my main browser window's search bar?